# Custom adapter results in loadingData problems

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm planning to create an application that fetches some data from a [SPARQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARQL) endpoint.
This endpoint doesn't contain tables, but RDF triples.

The data contained has to be transformed into the following models. The id's of these models are URI's (strings).

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    statistics: DS.hasMany('statistic', {async: true}),
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
App.Statistic = DS.Model.extend({
    category: DS.belongsTo('category'),
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I created custom adapters and serializers for each model, to handle custom queries and data transforms.

When I render all categories in a model, I want to also show the statistics in that model. I do this using the following partial:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="categories">
  <h2>Statistics</h2>
  <ul>
    {{#each category in model}}
      <li>{{category.title}}</li>
      <ul>
      {{#each statistic in category.statistics}}
      <li>{{statistic}}</li>
      {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

The router for this looks like this

```
App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('category');
    }
});
```

Using this approach I get the following Javascript error

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadingData` on    <App.Statistic:ember634:http://ewi.mmlab.be/geo#SportOffers> while in state root.loading.
```

Followed by multiple times this error

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Emptying a view in the inBuffer state is not allowed and should not happen under normal circumstances. Most likely there is a bug in your application. This may be due to excessive property change notifications.
```

I'm guessing this is related to the many calls to findMany in my statistic adapter, however I'm unsure of how to fix this.

All code can be seen at: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gedatizu/4/edit

Thanks in advance